# What does this mean in bash script: "if ! "$a" function "$b" $$ ; then"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am fairly new to bash scripting, working mostly in python till now.
What does this mean `if ! "$a" function "$b" $$ ; then` exactly in bash?

Where,
"a" is a variable,
"b" is a variable,
"function' is a custom function

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest that you remove the tags _linux_ and _ubuntu_, as they are irrelevant to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of variable `a` is taken to be a command (either an executable file, or a bash function). This command is invoked, and gets 3 parameters: The word `function`, the content of the variable `b`, and the PID of the process executing this `if`-statement.

After the command has terminated, its exit code is checked: If it is not zero, the `then` part of the compound is executed. This interpretation of the exit code is by virtue of the exclamation mark (`!`) in front. In general:

If you write a command as

```
! cmd
```

and the cmd itself would yield a non-zero exit code, the overall exit code of this statement (i.e. what goes into `$?`) is 0. If the cmd itself would yield the exit code zero. the overall exit code is 1.

Comment: No : in bash, if the command returns NOT 0, it does NOT execute the "then" part. 0 means there's no error while another value specifies the error. But in other languages like C, 0 means failed and 1 executed correctly.

Comment: @ATR : The `!` inverts the meaning. When you do a `if prog; then`, of course the _then_ part is executed when the exit code is 0. When, as in our case, you have a `if ! prog; then`, the _then_ part is executed if it is nonzero.

Comment: Totally true, I didn't think about that. You should mention that in your message.